# save recording video file on web server

Tags: ios, avcam

Hi I want to save recording video file from ipad to web server, I follow this link for video recording http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Read_Me_txt.html, so anybody can help for me how to do, I am fresher for this.